# Make widgets/frames inside tkinter canvas resizable

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a number of text widgets floating on a scrollable canvas widget. I want to allow users to resize them by dragging their edges and/or corners, possibly moving them if they drag the upper left edges or corner. I'm open to making them into frames with text widgets inside them, since I'm likely to do that anyway.

I figure I can handle the events manually if I can just get it to show resize handles. Do I need to catch mouseovers and clicks on a border myself?

Adding a "<Configure>" event binding does nothing, as one would expect. ttk.Sizegrip allegedly only works on top-level windows. There are lots of resources for preventing resizes, but very few for facilitating them, and they all seem to be for top-level windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up making a frame around the widget with a fat border, catching mouse events, and handling all the dirty resize logic myself.

I had to record both the initial location of the location of the click and the position of each successive mouse-move, and use them for top/left and bottom/right resizes, respectively.

Edit: Here's a handy (relatively) encapsulated implementation.

```
from Tkinter import *

class ResizableCanvasFrame(Frame):
    '''
    Class that handles creating resizable frames on a canvas.
    Don't pack it.

    Set save_callback to whatever you want to happen when the mouse
    lets up on the border. You can catch <Configure> too, but at least
    in my case I didn't want to save the new position on every mouse move.
    '''
    def __init__(self, master, x, y, w, h, *args, **kwargs):
        # master should be a Canvas
        self.frame_thickness = 5
        Frame.__init__(
            self,
            master,
            *args,
            borderwidth = self.frame_thickness,
            cursor = 'fleur',
            **kwargs
        )
        self.canvas = master
        self.resize_state = None
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.mousedown)
        self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.mousemove)
        self.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.mouseup)
        self.bind('<Destroy>', self.delete_item)
        # add self to canvas
        self.itemid = self.canvas.create_window(
            x,
            y,
            window=self,
            anchor="nw",
            width=w,
            height=h
        )
        self.save_callback = None

    def canvas_coords(self):
        return map(int, self.canvas.coords(self.itemid))

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        # strictly, this is out of the range of RCF,
        # but it helps with the law of demeter
        self.canvas.move(self.itemid, dx, dy)

    def mousedown(self, event):
        window_width = self.winfo_width()
        window_height = self.winfo_height()
        self.resize_state = {
            'start_coords': (event.x, event.y),
            'last_coords': (event.x, event.y),
            'left_edge': (0 <= event.x < self.frame_thickness),
            'right_edge': (window_width - self.frame_thickness <= event.x < window_width),
            'top_edge': (0 <= event.y < self.frame_thickness),
            'bottom_edge': (window_height - self.frame_thickness <= event.y < window_height),
        }            

    def mousemove(self, event):
        if self.resize_state:
            resize = self.resize_state # debug var
            event_x = event.x
            event_y = event.y
            # distance of cursor from original position of window
            delta = map(int, (event.x - self.resize_state['start_coords'][0],
                              event.y - self.resize_state['start_coords'][1]))
            # load current pos, size
            new_x, new_y = self.canvas_coords()
            new_width = int(self.canvas.itemcget(self.itemid, 'width'))
            new_height = int(self.canvas.itemcget(self.itemid, 'height'))
            # handle x resize/move
            if self.resize_state['left_edge']:
                # must move pos and resize
                new_x += delta[0]
                new_width -= delta[0]
            elif self.resize_state['right_edge']:
                new_width += (event.x - self.resize_state['last_coords'][0])
            # handle y resize/move
            if self.resize_state['top_edge']:
                new_y += delta[1]
                new_height -= delta[1]
            elif self.resize_state['bottom_edge']:
                new_height += (event.y - self.resize_state['last_coords'][1])
            # save new settings in item, not card yet
            self.resize_state['last_coords'] = (event.x, event.y)
            self.canvas.coords(self.itemid, new_x, new_y)
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.itemid, width=new_width, height=new_height)

    def mouseup(self, event):
        if self.resize_state:
            self.resize_state = None
            if self.save_callback:
                self.save_callback()

    def delete_item(self, event):
        self.canvas.delete(self.itemid)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `PanedWindow` widget, or a combination of a few of them, inside your canvas. They are designed to do that. Getting the `PanedWindow` to stretch like the "sticky" command inside the canvas is an unknown though.

That is what I was looking for when stumbled across this post.